# Continuity of $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ implies continuity of $f(t) = \displaystyle \min_{a \leq x \leq t}f(x)$ at [a,b].

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Let $f(x)$  be a continuous function
>    on $[a,b]$.
>
> Show that $F(t) = \displaystyle \min_{a\leq x\leq t}f(x)$ is also continuous on $[a,b]$.

Statement seems obvious for me, especially  when I try to draw some special cases of this problem, but I fail to derive a rigorous proof.

Comment: $\min_{a<x<t} f(x)$ is not defined at $t=a$. And in general the minimum need not exist anywhere at all. I suppose you mean $\le $ throughout

Comment: Have you tried to write down what is it that you need to prove? A definition of continuity? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Also "$f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$" and "on $[a,b]$" are mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Hagen, thanks, $\le$, of course.

Comment: @user658409 fixed.